# Read JsonResult in javascript from webservice in asp.net c#

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, json, web-services

I am trying to read json result in javascript but it gives me error.

it gives me error on **var jsonObj = JSON.parse(msg);**.
Error:**Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o**
When i debug the code Webservice return perfect json data,but it give error on success event in ajax.
How i can loop through this json object??Any help appreciated.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        var ProductCategoryList;

        function callpageload() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "WebService1.asmx/GetCategoryList",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (msg) {
                    var jsonObj = JSON.parse(msg);
                },
                error: function (msg) {

                }
            });
        }

</script>
```

Webservice code

```
public string GetCategoryList()
        {
            DataSet ds = Persistance.GetCategoryList();
            List<ProductCategories> prodlst = new List<ProductCategories>();
            if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    ProductCategories prod = new ProductCategories();
                    prod.pid = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["pid"].ToString();
                    prod.id = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["id"].ToString();
                    prod.name = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["name"].ToString();
                    prodlst.Add(prod);
                }

            }
            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(prodlst.ToArray());
            return json;
        }
```

Comment: What error? i don't see any error.

Comment: Set the option `dataType: 'json'` for your `ajax` . I don't think you need to parse the response anyways as it already in json format.

Answer (score 0):

try parsing `msg.d`.
also use POST; it's more secure.

Answer (score -1):

Hey I had a similar problem. For me I was using JQuery too.

Instead of your

```
var jsonObj = JSON.parse(msg);
```

Try to use

```
var jsonObj = $.parseJSON(msg);
```

One more thing I would suggest checking is put a breakpoint in your c# end to make sure that there are no exceptions or errors when you are using newtonsoft JSONconvert. This happens many times that it returns an empty json string.

Let me know if this helps.

Somewhere in my code someone had done var JSON={}
So it caused an error.

Comment: $.parseJSON uses JSON.parse if it is available, so... this is unlikely to have any effect.

Comment: The Jquery Version worked for me. So I just posted here with what my experience was.